# PhpStorm unable to unlock files (Ionic)

Tags: php, permissions, phpstorm, ionic-framework, chmod

I'm making a webapp using Laravel 5 as backend and Ionic as frontend.

The IDE I'm using is PhpStorm 8 but I've been running into a problem.

Whenever I try to make a new Ionic project (ionic start myApp tabs/sidemenu...) the folder gets locked in PhpStorm, I cannot edit a single file, I get a pop up with 'clear read only status' but clicking OK does not change anything.

I've tried several things: placing the folder everywhere on my HD, creating Ionic folder as `sudo`, adding `chmod 777`. At first I've added the ionic folder to my backend project, then I made them stand-alone too, but nothing seems to work: I cannot edit a file in my Ionic project.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/swpkra.jpg]

Every kind of help would be helpful since I'm really stuck right now...

Answer (score -1):

It might be a little bit late since the question is over a year old, but what user is owner of the file? For instance if your user is `your-username-here:staff` but your folder/file is owned by `_www:_www` Phpstorm won't be able to open the file since it runs as `your-username`.

To remedy this you could add your user to the group that owns the file (or folder).

On MacOs you can do the following: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a`whoami`-t user _www` if the owner of the group is `_www` and restart finder with `killall Finder`.

Hope this helps.